# How to add an event in a lambda resource that will be triggered by an API gateway in an AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to create an AWS SAM template which has a lambda which should be triggered by an API gateway.

The SAM template is only for the API gateway, and *not* for the API gateway. The API gateway will be created manually, and exists before the SAM template is deployed.

I understand that the way to do that is, under the resource I add :

```
Events:
 APIName:
  Type: Api
  Properties:
   Method : post
   Path : /group/user
   RestApiId:
    Ref: MyApi
```

An example can be looked into [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-template.html).

What I don't understand is, how *exactly* should I be using this for my use case.

Questions that I have:

- API Name : What is to be put here? I used the exact API name, which is already created in the AWS account, and I got an error that the event id is invalid.
- How do I uniquely identify my API? : Let's say we have two APIs with the same path `/sendMesage`, then how would the template know *which* API gateway is to be referred to? I think it has something to do with the RestApiId, but I am not sure, because it's not a required field.
- Can we not link up existing API gateway? : One possible issue that I think that might be in play here would be that we can't actually link an existing API gateway as a trigger for a lambda that would be created after deploying the SAM stack. But this is limiting, and I am not sure if this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get the questions one by one and hopefully I'll be of some help

***API Name : What is to be put here?***
This is just an identifier for the API event you're creating. I normally use some form of description for the endpoint. Whatever you end up doing, try to have some convention or it will become hard to read (Http verb then action for instance, GetAllUsers)

***How do I uniquely identify my API? :***
It kinda feels like you actually have two different responsibilities and thus possibly two different path names here. If sendMessage can send a message to a group or to a user then you could have `sendMessageToGroup` and `sendMessageToUser` thus making them more explicit.

***Can we not link up existing API gateway? :***
It would appear not [judging by the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-httpapi.html#sam-function-httpapi-apiid) but I might be wrong on that one.